# Ignore a more tag when using get_the_content()

Tags: read-more

This is such a simple question it seems yet I can't find a definite answer on it.

So how do you make `get_the_content()` obtain all the content of a post even if it has `<!--more-->` inside of the text which normally makes the function return after it has been used ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just get the raw content from `$post->post_content`, strip the `<!--more-->` and then do whatever you need with the result. Just remember, `$post->post_content` and `get_the_content()` both return **unfiltered** text, if you need filtered content, simply apply the `the_content` filter to the result from those two results

### EXAMPLE inside the LOOP

```
global $post;
$unfiltered_content = str_replace( '<!--more-->', '', $post->post_content );
// If you need filtered content returned
$filtered_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $unfiltered_content );
// Output filtered content
echo $filtered_content;
```